# Absolute positioned Content of absolute positioned DIV is not displayed

Tags: html

There is a large absolute positioned Div with lots of absolute positioned content in it.

Source Looks like this:

```
<div id="masterdiv" 
style="display:block;position:absolute;
left:0;top:0;width:595pt;background:white;">

<IMG WIDTH=793 HEIGHT=1121  
style="border:2px solid lightgrey;background:white;left:0pt;top:0pt;
width:595pt;height:841pt;" SRC="../../xyz" id="masterbild">

<p style="left:574.75pt;top:67.05pt;font-family:Arial;font-size:11pt;">
<b>W1</b>
</p>

<p style="left:160pt;top:71.15pt;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;">
<b>Rohrbearbeitungs-<SPAN style="word-spacing:0.05pt;"> </SPAN>
und<SPAN style="word-spacing:0.05pt;"> </SPAN>Handwerkzeuge</b>
</p>

....
</div>
```

### The problem (IE9!):

I cant scroll to the end of the div content. The scrollbar of the browser and the div itself stops at a certain point (bottom) of the page. But this is NOT the end of the content. If I put the "top" style value of "masterdiv" to -400px I can see theres actually more content.

### Pictures

Bottom of the Page:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/337/seitenende.jpg/

Changed Top to -400px:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/gendertertop.jpg/

### Things I tried:

Setting "Masterdiv" to 100% height or "1500px" or whatever doenst work.
Setting Body to "1500px" affects the scrollbar, but the content of the div is still ending at some certain point.
I combined these two things without succes.

### EDIT: Solution:

Body Tag had "position:fixed" on it. I dropped it and it worked.

**What can I do?**

**Im forced to use position:absolute.**

Comment: could you pleeeease format your html properly, i doubt that anybody has the patience to work through that hell to help you :)

Comment: thanks Ill work on it. Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: how do you mean ending, is the div box stopping before all the content is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the whitespace style tag, or try fiddling around with the overflow options, it should expand automatically at that point, but not too sure about how IE9 behaves.

**EDIT**

It might be the default settings for the iframe. Try seeing if setting the scrolling parameter to "yes" within the iframe

Comment: did you take a look at the pictures Ive added recently?

Comment: unfortunately theres no effect :(

Comment: have try allowing scroll bars (scrolling="yes"), and set the overflow style property to auto, or maybe even visible (both on iframe), it might be an aggregate thing. Hang on, whats the doctype set as? IE is particularly sensitive to it

Comment: thanks for the effort, but this didnt work either :(
Firefox handles everything correct by the way...
If I drop the doctype everythings fine, but thats not what I want to do. The doctype is "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">" at the moment.

Comment: Dont focus on the Iframe. Page looks equal without an Iframe!

Comment: IE9 likes to make the next page inherit the defined DOCTYPE too, but what are you trying to use the iframe to view in particular?